# Correctly changing default locale in ubuntu server 10.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, localization, language

I got a new server but unfortunately the hoster only installs me Ubuntu 8.04 in german.

So the upgrade worked smoothly, but now I am trying to change the system to english.

I adapted `/etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
LANG="en_us.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="de_DE:en_US:de_LU:de_CH:de_BE:de_AT"
```

And after searching forums I installed `update-locale` which generated the file `/etc/default/locale`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
LANG="en_us.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="de_DE:en_US:de_LU:de_CH:de_BE:de_AT"
```

(this is the file i commonly remember from debian systems to hold the locale)

then i did `dpkg-reconfigure locales` which configured all the locales and after log out and relogin almost everything was in english.

*almost*

the welcome messages is. the programs come in english. but for example apt is not:

```
prag341:~# apt-get upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Status-Informationen einlesen... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert:
  linux-image-generic
1 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen 4,346B an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren [J/n]?
```

which is a very bad thing because then the default arguments Y/N become exchanged by J/N etc.

How can i correctly change the locale to default us english in uft8 as if i had installed it from the beginnig?

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale.

Comment: thats what i already looked like. one file did not exist in the first place and was added be update-locale. i configured both accordintly

Comment: here is an examle how to install or reinstall locale
http://linux-ubuntu.info/en/how-to-change-the-default-locale/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close! You just need to change your preferred language list

From this

`LANGUAGE="de_DE:en_US:de_LU:de_CH:de_BE:de_AT"`

To this

`LANGUAGE="en_US"`

Once this is done reboot your server and all the system languages should be in English

Comment: thanks! it worked. but can you explain why? i just re arranged them and put en_us in the front. why did that not work??

Comment: No need to reboot, you can do export LANGUAGE="en_US" in the command line or just source /etc/profile right? May not be applied for all programs but apt-get was in English after I did that

Answer (score 0):

But first you need to have needed language pack installed. On my German based VPS there was no english language pack pre-installed. So first you check that you have it installed:

```
aptitude install language-pack-en
```